# Clash of Clans war tiebreaker

Tags: clash-of-clans

During a Clash of Clans war, which team is determined to win when the star total is even and the total destruction is also even?

Answer (score 1):

When both teams have a same amount of war stars, then it is a **draw** and neither one clan gets the clan XP for victory. If some clan has in the clan description the warlog, then it will be counted as the last space (wins/loses/draws). Example: 5/4/1